# Encoding problem when generating user in Microsoft Graph

Tags: powershell, character-encoding, microsoft-graph-api, invoke-restmethod

What character encoding should a POST body to /v1.0/users have?

I have problems with generating users with accented characters in the name with Microsoft Graph.

I use the following body:

```json
{
    "accountEnabled":false,
    "displayName":"ADM Joost Müller",
    "userprincipalname":"admjmuller@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com",
    "mailNickname":"admjmuller",
    "passwordProfile":{      
        "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn":true,
        "forceChangePasswordNextSignInWithMfa":true,
        "password":"Randompasswordgenerated"
    }
}
```

When calling POST to /v1.0/users with the above JSON in the body I get the following object back:

```
@odata.context    : https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity
id                : xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-a72a188e6d9a
businessPhones    : {}
displayName       : ADM Joost M�ller
givenName         : 
jobTitle          : 
mail              : 
mobilePhone       : 
officeLocation    : 
preferredLanguage : 
surname           : 
userPrincipalName : admjmuller@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com
```

Note the '�' in the displayname. This is NOT a display problem in Powershell, the Entra ID blade in the Azure portal also shows this character.
I've already tried to forcibly convert the JSON to UTF-8:

```
$enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$jsonutf8 = $enc.getstring($enc.getbytes($json))
```

but that didn't solve the problem.

I've tried various search terms but can't find anything that points to a solution. It's probably something trivial but if it is, I'm using the wrong search terms...

The actual code:

```
function Encode {
  Param(
    [string]$text
  )
  $enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::Utf8
  return $enc.getstring($enc.getbytes($text))
}

function Invoke-GraphPost {
  [cmdletbinding()]
  Param(
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$API,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$AccessToken,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]$body,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $false)][string]$Apiversion = "v1.0"
  )
  $header = @{
    Authorization  = ("Bearer {0}" -f $AccessToken)
    'Content-Type' = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
  }
  $bodyjson = Encode(ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $body -Compress)
  $URI = Encode(("https://graph.microsoft.com/{0}/{1}" -f $Apiversion, $API))
  try {
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URI -Method Post -Body $bodyjson -Headers $header
  }
  catch {
    $FailMessage = ("Unable to create graph POST request {0} with body {1}" -f $URI, $bodyjson)
    $module.failjson($FailMessage)
  }
  return $result
}

      $password = [System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword(12, 4)
      $upnbase = New-EntraUserName -NameFormat "$adminprefix$format" -Voornaam $User.Roepnaam -Infix $User.Voorv_gebnaam -Achternaam $User.Geboortenaam -Domainname $admindomain
      $body = @{
        accountEnabled    = $false
        displayName       = ("ADM {0} {1}" -f $User.Roepnaam.Trim(), $User.Volledige_achternaam.Trim())
        mailNickname      = $upnbase
        userprincipalname = ("{0}@{1}" -f $upnbase, $admindomain)
        passwordProfile   = @{
          forceChangePasswordNextSignIn        = $true
          forceChangePasswordNextSignInWithMfa = $true
          password                             = $password
        }
      }
$newuser = Invoke-GraphPost -API users -AccessToken $token.access_token -body $body
```

where `New-EntraUserName` generates a unique username based on givenname, infix and surname (that exact code is irrelevant for the problem, for Joost Müller, the generated username is admjmuller, so without accent).

Joost

Comment: Where is the payload stored, how do you retrieve it, and what does "calling POST to /v1.0/users" look like? Please share the exact command (or better, a complete snippet with which you can reproduce the issue) :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen code snippet added.

Comment: If you look in the Entra portal, does the name look normal or are the characters also replaced? I've had a lot of problems with unicode charachters displaying correctly in the default Windows console. In the "new" terminal unicode characters display correct on my machine.

Comment: The code you've posted is still incomplete? What is `$User`? If you read it from a CSV file, did you specify the `-Encoding` with `Import-Csv` or `Get-Content`?

Comment: It's UTF-8 data from our HR system. But even if it was e.g. Unicode, shouldn't the Encode convert it to UTF-8 for the POST?
And I generated a test JSON object directly by typing in the data in the Powershell console, that should definitely be UTF-8.

Comment: @bluuf Portal also shows the � symbol.

Comment: The powershell window may not use a font that displays the character.  Try changing the PS Font : https://www.isumsoft.com/windows-10/change-windows-powershell-font-layout.html

Comment: @jdweng The portal shows the � symbol as well.

Comment: As an aside: PowerShell functions, cmdlets, scripts, and external programs must be invoked _like shell commands_ - `foo $val` - _not_ like C# methods - `foo($val)`.  It happens to work with a _single_ argument, but breaks with multiple ones, because if you use `,` to separate arguments, you'll construct an _array_ that a command sees as a _single argument_.

Comment: @jdweng, let me plead again: Please stop confusing others by erroneously conflating _fonts_ (which determine the appearance of already-known characters) and _character encodings_ (which determine how _raw bytes_, as used in persisted storage and cross-process / network communication, are _interpreted as_ characters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **request body is *not* being submitted with the expected [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)** character encoding, for the following reasons:

- Your `Encode` function is a *no-op*: it converts a string to *and back from* a UTF-8 byte representation, so that you're ending up with the same *.NET* string (of type [`[string]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String), which is internally composed of UTF-16 Unicode code units).
- Thus, you're passing a regular `[string]` instance to the `-Body` parameter and are therefore delegating the decision as to what character encoding to use to
  [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) (the following applies analogously to [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) as well):

  - While you're trying to indicate the desired encoding via a *header* field, - the `'Content-Type' = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'` entry in the hashtable you're passing to `-Header` - ***PowerShell 7.3-*, including *Windows PowerShell***, unfortunately does *not* honor this, and **default to [ISO-8559-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) encoding**.

    - However, a `charset` attribute as part of the separate `-ContentType` parameter *is* honored (see below).
  - [PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) **7.4+** now honors a header field too and in the *absence* of a `charset` attribute now **defaults to UTF-8**.

---

**Solutions**:

- **PowerShell 7.4+**:

  - Given the above, your code should work as-is - except that you don't need the redundant `Encode` call.
- **PowerShell 7.3- and Windows PowerShell**:

  - Option 1:

    - Omit the (pointless) `Encode` call.
    - Don't add a `Content-Type` entry to `$header`.
    - Instead, **add** a **`-ContentType 'application/json; charset=utf-8'`** argument to the `Invoke-RestMethod` call.
  - Option 2:

    - **Perform the UTF-8 encoding *yourself*** and **pass a *byte array*** to the **`-Body`** parameter:

      ```bash
       Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URI -Method Post -Headers $header -Body (
         [Text.UTF8Encoding]::new().GetBytes(
           (ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $body -Compress)
         )
       )
      ```