# JSON rejected for invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xa0, but encoding appears vaild

Tags: json, powershell, utf-8, character-encoding, invoke-webrequest

I'm creating a JSON file in PowerShell 7.4 to send to a 3rd party REST endpoint.  `Out-File` defaults to UTF-8, and when I check the file in Notepad++, the encoding setting appears as UTF-8.  Unfortunately, the POST is being rejected with the message:

```
400 Bad Request
JSON parse error
Nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xa0\n at line: 9259, column: 38
```

I examined the JSON line specified in the error message.  The source JSON file has a *NO-BREAK SPACE* sequence in its company name as follows:

```
String        Hex
------------  --------------------------------------
"Acme, Inc."  22 41 63 6d 65 2c c2 a0 49 6e 63 2e 22
```

*NO-BREAK SPACE* in UTF-8 appears as two bytes: `0xc2 0xa0`.  Both characters are present in the JSON file, but the error indicates that the remote parser isn't processing the first character as part of the sequence.

Here's the PowerShell script:

```
# identify CSV file

   $csvFile = Get-ChildItem -Path ($path + '*.csv') -File | 
                 Sort-Object LastWriteTime | 
                 Select-Object -First 1 

# suppress blank lines

   $objData = Get-Content $csvFile -Encoding UTF8 | 
                 Where-Object { $_ } | 
                 ConvertFrom-CSV

# convert to JSON and save to file
     
   $body = $objData | 
              ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100

   $body | 
      Out-File ( $path + 'data.json')
        
# post JSON

    $webParam = @{
       Uri         = $url 
       Method      = 'POST' 
       Headers     =  @{ 'Authorization' = $auth
                         'Cache-Control' = 'no-cache' }
       Body        = $body 
       ContentType = 'application/json'
    }
  
$apiResponse = Invoke-WebRequest @webParam
```

The data is usually different each time the script runs.  On most occasions, the remote site will accept the JSON without an issue because it doesn't have any oddball Unicode characters.

I'm not sure why the remote site doesn't like the string, but the error makes sense if it can't distinguish the entire two-byte sequence.  PowerShell's `Test-JSON` cmdlet always evaluates as true before I send.  Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: @mklement0 I don't know why the error shows the newline. After the end quote, there's a comma before newline in the file, which doesn't show in the error message.

Comment: please post the part of the code involved. Also: are you SURE there is no `NO-BREAK SPACE` in the source data?

Comment: @sirtao The _NO-BREAK SPACE_ **does** exist in the JSON data.  Since it appears to be valid UTF-8, I'm asking why it's being rejected.  I added the code to the question.

Comment: You are not uploading the FILE, you are uploading the VARIABLE. Which means whatever happens in the file is irrelevant.

(One small pointer: use `Import-Csv -Encoding utf8` directly. It also automatically ignores empty lines. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure that PowerShell uses UTF-8 encoding also in versions 7.3.x and below (including Windows PowerShell) when it transmits the .NET [`string`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String) passed to the `-Body` parameter of [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest), use
`-ContentType 'application/json; charset=utf-8'` (in PowerShell 7.4+, this is no longer necessary); applied to your [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting) scenario:

```
    $webParam = @{
       Uri         = $url 
       Method      = 'POST' 
       Headers     =  @{ 'Authorization' = $auth
                         'Cache-Control' = 'no-cache' }
       Body        = $body 
       # Note the addition of '; charset=utf-8'
       ContentType = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    }
  
$apiResponse = Invoke-WebRequest @webParam
```

- That you originally read your text from a UTF-8 file is irrelevant in this case, because by using a .NET string you're delegating the decision as to what character encoding to use to `Invoke-WebRequest`, and in versions before 7.4 that encoding is [ISO-8559-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

  - In this *single-byte* encoding, the code point of the NO-BREAK SPACE ([`U+00A0`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0)) character is `0xa` *alone* - which amounts to an *illegal start byte of a multi-byte UTF-8 sequence* encoding a non-ASCII character - this is what your target server complained about.
  - In fact, because ISO-8559-1 forms the *8-bit subrange* of [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) and because of how the [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) Unicode encoding works, all Unicode code points in the range `0x80` - `0xbf` are *two-byte* sequences whose first byte is `0xc2`, followed by a byte with the *same value as the code point*.
  - Thus, NO-BREAK SPACE ([`U+00A0`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0)) - the character whose code point is `0xa0` in *both* Unicode (abstractly) and ISO-8559-1 (as a concrete, single-byte value) - is the two-byte sequence `0xc2 0xa0` in UTF-8.
    Because, due to mistaken ISO-8559-1 encoding, only `0xa0` was transmitted, it *appeared* as if the target server ignored the `0xc2`, but in actuality *it never received it*.
- See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77827631/45375) for additional information about PowerShell's behavior (which equally applies to the [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) cmdlet).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  I see the 7.4 documentation clarifies the default encoding.